# Sleuth tracer.currentSpan() coming as empty in WebFlux WebFilter

Tags: spring-boot, spring-webflux, spring-cloud-sleuth

How Can I add Trace Id in the response headers in reactive WebFlux context ? I have tried with the below code but the span is always coming as null. Sleuth dependency version is 3.0.3 and Spring Boot version is 2.5.4

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.cloud.sleuth.Span;
import org.springframework.cloud.sleuth.Tracer;
import org.springframework.core.Ordered;
import org.springframework.core.annotation.Order;
import org.springframework.http.server.reactive.ServerHttpResponse;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.web.server.ServerWebExchange;
import org.springframework.web.server.WebFilter;
import org.springframework.web.server.WebFilterChain;
import reactor.core.publisher.Mono;

@Component
public class GatewaySleuthFilter implements WebFilter {

    @Autowired
    Tracer tracer;
    
    @Override
      public Mono<Void> filter(ServerWebExchange exchange,
                               WebFilterChain chain) {
        ServerHttpResponse response = exchange.getResponse();
        response.beforeCommit(() -> {
          Span span = tracer.currentSpan();
          if (span != null) {
            exchange.getResponse().getHeaders().add("trace-id", span.context().traceId());
            exchange.getResponse().getHeaders().add("span-id", span.context().spanId());
          }
          return Mono.empty();
        });
        return chain.filter(exchange);
      }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The below code worked for me.

```
@Override
    public Mono<Void> filter(ServerWebExchange exchange, WebFilterChain chain) {
        ServerHttpResponse response = exchange.getResponse();
        response.beforeCommit(() -> {
            Span span = exchange.getAttribute(Span.class.getName());
            if (span != null) {
                exchange.getResponse().getHeaders().add(TRACE_ID_HEADER, span.context().traceId());
                exchange.getResponse().getHeaders().add(SPAN_ID_HEADER, span.context().spanId());
            }
            return Mono.empty();
        });
        return chain.filter(exchange);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Using a `WebFilter` would be the right way to do this, the [docs suggest something similar](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-sleuth/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#how-to-add-headers-to-the-http-server-response).
I'm not sure why exactly do you get this behavior (I guess `beforeCommit` might not be in the context), this is what the docs suggest, I would try this first:

```java
@Bean
WebFilter traceIdInResponseFilter(Tracer tracer) {
    return (exchange, chain) -> {
        Span span = tracer.currentSpan();
        if (span != null) {
            exchange.getResponse().getHeaders().add("trace-id", span.context().traceId());
            exchange.getResponse().getHeaders().add("span-id", span.context().spanId());
        }
        return chain.filter(exchange);
    };
}
```

Here are a few other pointers for troubleshooting:

- Please check if your spans are sampled
- Please check if a Span was created and you are in the context of it
- Could you please check if any other [instrumentation style](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-sleuth/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#sleuth-reactor-integration) works (I recommend `DECORATE_QUEUES`)?

Comment: Thanks for the response. 
Tried the above mentioned code, and tracer.currentSpan() is still coming as null.
I am unsure on how to check if a Span is getting sampled at runtime. Trying to figure out at the moment.

For Sleuth Integration with WebFlux, I have only added the sleuth maven dependency. Anything else need to be explicitly configured?

Answer (score 0):

The current span is `null` because the default instrumentation option in the Gateway is manual. So you're responsible for retrieving the spans. So you have two options.

Option no 1 is to use `WebFluxSleuthOperators` to retrieve the current trace context from the `ServerWebExchange` (https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-sleuth/blob/v3.0.4/spring-cloud-sleuth-instrumentation/src/main/java/org/springframework/cloud/sleuth/instrument/web/WebFluxSleuthOperators.java) as follows:

```java
@Bean
WebFilter traceIdInResponseFilter() {
    return (exchange, chain) -> {
        Span span = 
WebFluxSleuthOperators.currentTraceContext(exchange);
        if (span != null) {
            exchange.getResponse().getHeaders().add("trace-id", span.context().traceId());
            exchange.getResponse().getHeaders().add("span-id", span.context().spanId());
        }
        return chain.filter(exchange);
    };
}
```

or option number 2 go with the different Sleuth Reactor integration as Jontan mentioned https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-sleuth/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#sleuth-reactor-integration as follows:

```
spring:
  sleuth:
    reactor:
      # try decorate_queues and if that fails decorate_on_each
      # decorate_on_each can lead to dramatic performance degradation
      instrumentation-type: decorate_queues
```

Comment: Thanks Marcin for the Response.
On trying the option number 1,  the TraceContext is returning null.
WebFluxSleuthOperators.currentTraceContext(exchange); // returning null.
Anything else we need to do explicitly as part of the configuration